# System.out.println is not printing output?

Tags: java, palindrome

I am trying to have the list for palindrome but it doesn't give any kind of output. But it works when I am checking for palindrome.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num=0 ,org=0 , rem = 0,rev=0 ,a=0;
        for(num=12 ; num<=101; num++) {
            org=num ;

            while(num>0) {
                rem = num % 10 ; 
                num = num /10 ;
                rev= (10*rev)+rem;
            }

            if(rev==org)
                System.out.println(org);
        }
    }
}
```

Why am I not getting any output?

Comment: "but it works when i am checking for palindrome" - what's your definition of "works"? Seeing output?

Comment: I mean this logic works when i am using for checking that is a palindrome or not ! but for listing down it doesn't works. @MarounMaroun

Comment: @user3163224 Yes, the logic is correct for testing a single number, but the for loop is wrong.

Comment: @Eran what wiil it be ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two errors :

1. You should reset `rev` to 0 in each iteration (otherwise, `rev` would only be correct in the first iteration).
2. You should add `num=org;` at the end of each iteration, to restore the value of your loop variable. Otherwise, the loop may never terminate, since you are messing with the loop variable inside the body of the loop.

It should look like this :

```
for(num=12 ; num<=101; num++) {   
    org=num ;   
    rev = 0; // added
    while(num>0) {
      rem = num % 10 ; 
      num = num /10 ;
      rev= (10*rev)+rem;
    }
    if(rev==org)
        System.out.println(org);
    num = org; // added
}
```

Output :

```
22
33
44
55
66
77
88
99
101
```